# Django Cookie Value inside template

Tags: python, django, cookies

I want to show additional links in the layout, if there is a certain named cookie inside the request. I've managed to access  'request' variable inside the template. I made the following:

```
 {% if request.COOKIES.['cookie_name'] %}
   <li><a href="{% url 'felhasznalo:felhasznalo-detail' %}">some link</a></li>
 {% endif  %}
```

but it throws this error: `TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '['cookie_name']' from 'request.COOKIES.['cookie_name']'`

what am I doing wrong? (the cookie is exists, and if i print out request.COOKIES, it writes out all the containing cookie's names, and it's values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

use

```
{% if request.COOKIES.cookie_name %}
   <li><a href="{% url 'felhasznalo:felhasznalo-detail' %}">some link</a></li>
{% endif  %}
```

> Variables and lookups
>
> Variable names must consist of any letter (A-Z), any digit (0-9), an
>   underscore (but they must not start with an underscore) or a dot.
>
> Dots have a special meaning in template rendering. A dot in a variable
>   name signifies a lookup. Specifically, when the template system
>   encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups,
>   in this order:
>
> ```
> Dictionary lookup. Example: foo["bar"]
> Attribute lookup. Example: foo.bar
> List-index lookup. Example: foo[bar]
> ```

Comment: Hi, the provided link is dead.

Comment: link updated to latest version of django 1, also the content of the 1.9 version is still c/p in the answer